# Subdividing a curve with points equal to distance between points

Tags: three.js, curve

In three.js I have `push`ed some `Vector3()` coordinates into a variable, and I perform `THREE.CatmullRomCurve3(points).getPoints(points*32);` to get a curve. If I extrude a shape along it, it all looks fine.

The problem I am having now is that I want the camera to run along this curve, but the speed changes depending on how far it is from one (original) point to another. According to one of the examples from threejs.org, I loop through each of the new points and set the camera's position to those points. But if two points are 1 meters apart, or 2 meters apart, it is still 32 subpoints between each, and the camera will reach the end in the exact same time.

How can I do so that a 1 meter stretch gets 32 subpoints, and a 2 meter stretch gets 64 subpoints, and so the camera will take twice as long to complete the 2 meter stretch compared to the 1 meter stretch?

Comment: Please show your code (in [mcve] form, ideally)

Answer (score 0):

> The problem I am having now is that I want the camera to run along this curve, but the speed changes depending on how far it is from one (original) point to another.

If you use [Curve.getSpacedPoints()](https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#api/en/extras/core/Curve.getSpacedPoints) instead of `Curve.getPoints()`, you will receive equi-spaced points along your curve.

`three.js R106`

Comment: I tried that. The camera still ran at varying speeds.

Comment: Can you animate your camera similar to this example? https://threejs.org/examples/webgl_geometry_extrude_splines (Click on `animationView` and/or `cameraHelper` for debugging).

Comment: For some reason I am having a hard time reading this, but if I understand it correctly `getPointAt()` accepts a `float`? So that if I were to give it the time between frames it would keep the speed consistent?